# StringTemplates exception

Tags: java, antlr, stringtemplate

I have java-code:

```
    StringTemplate message = new StringTemplate("Hello, $name$");
    message.setAttribute("name", "Ann");
```

But I have exception:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: antlr/TokenStream
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: antlr.TokenStream
```

So I have antlr-3.2.jar file and CLASSPATH:../lib/antlr-3.2.jar.
maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where is a mistake?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to address your problem.

Comment: @Emrakul, that you are still interested?

Comment: you should switch to v4 if at all possible as soon as possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the complete dependency jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr-complete</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```